# How can we add arch specific conflicts tag when building .deb package?

Tags: apt, dpkg

We are trying to build multi-arch supported i386 .deb package.
There are two .deb packages build on i386 X1 & X2 (X2 is a subset of X1 binaries).
X1 <-> X2 conflict each other when installing . Only one .deb package can be installed at any instance.

We similarly have binaries on xa64 arch. 
Again on xa64, there are two .deb packages X1 & X2 (X2 is a subset of X1 binaries).
X1 <-> X2 conflict each other when installing . Only one .deb package can be installed at any instance.

In case of multi-arch i386 .deb package,i386 .deb packages (X1 & X2) can be installed on xa64 along side with 64bit  (X1 & X2)

However I see that when installing 
X1:i386 & X1:amd64 can co-exist 
However, it throws conflict error when trying to install
X1:i386 & X2:amd64

In short, Can we mark package to conflict based on arch
Conflict: X2:i386

X1:i386 package should only conflict with X2:i386 & allow other packages to co-exist
X1:amd64 package should only conflict with X2:amd64 & allow other packages to co-exist

X1:i386  can co-exist with X1:amd64 OR X2:amd64
X2:i386 can co-exist with X1:amd64 OR X2:amd64

Thanks for your reply

Comment: I think your have two options. Your first and best option is to resovle the conflict. "Be aware that adding Conflicts is normally not the best solution when two packages provide the same files. Depending on the reason for that conflict, using alternatives or renaming the files is often a better approach. See, for example, Binaries, Section 10.1. " https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html . If the conflict can not be resolved, IMO ,you are best off building a 32 bit an 64 bit package as packaging is no longer arch independent.

Comment: For details on how to resolve the conflict see https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s-binaries

Comment: I suppose if X2 is a subset of X1, perhaps make 2 independent packages, and list X2 as a dependency of X1

Answer (score 1):

> Relationships may be restricted to a certain set of architectures.
>   This is indicated in brackets after each individual package name and
>   the optional version specification. The brackets enclose a non-empty
>   list of Debian architecture names in the format described in
>   Architecture specification strings, Section 11.1, separated by
>   whitespace. Exclamation marks may be prepended to each of the names.
>   (It is not permitted for some names to be prepended with exclamation
>   marks while others aren't.)

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html

This manual provides a set of examples, see for instance:

```
Depends: foo [i386], bar [amd64]
```

You may be able to use arch-specific `Conflicts:` and `Replaces:` with this syntax. I'm unsure how to say "X1 conflicts/replaces X2 of the same architecture", that's for you to research/try. I'm not sure if something like this would work:

```
package: X1
Architecture: i386
Conflicts: X2 [i386]
Replaces: X2 [i386]

package: X1
Architecture: amd64 
Conflicts: X2 [amd64]
Replaces: X2 [amd64]

package: X2
Architecture: i386
Conflicts: X1 [i386]
Replaces: X1 [i386]

package: X2
Architecture: amd64 
Conflicts: X1 [amd64]
Replaces: X1 [amd64]
```

I'm unsure if you can have two packages with the same name but different architectures. Still, it's a starting point for you to experiment. Be sure to read the policy manual, chapter 7 describes how relationships work in great detail.

Comment: OP responded to your answer by writing an answer that was not an answer... Any insight? I'm trying to do cleanup :)